# How to debug windows version adb.exe?

Tags: android, windows, linux, debugging

I've build the whole android source code and adb.exe with MINGW=yes. But how to debug it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MinGw comes with a tool set of gdb, so it's almost the same with debugging in linux.

Answer (score 1):

gdb is the tool of choice to debug Android. Google for "debugging android with gdb" for references. A good point to start is http://www.omappedia.org/wiki/Android_Debugging.